# Dividing jobs for threads in Cuda using Thrust

Tags: parallel-processing, cuda, thrust

I have a testing code that needs to update keys inside a device_vector of a class. Therefore, how do I divide portions of the work to especific threads?

Example of the code without the division:

```
__global__ void UpdateKeys(Request* vector, int size, int seed, int qt_threads){
   curandState_t state;
   curand_init(seed, threadIdx.x, 0, &state);
   int id = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
   if(id < size){
       vector[i].key_ = (curand(&state % 100) / 100;
   }
}
```

That vector is passed as a thrust::device_vector.

Examples of what I want:

1000 keys and 2000 threads: use only 1000 and give a key to each one. 
1000 keys and 1000 threads: use it all. 
1 key and 100 threads: use 1 thread. 
500 keys and 250 threads: each thread take care of 2. 
240 keys and 80 threads: each thread take care of 3.

Comment: "e.g. 500 keys to update using 1000 threads, so each thread needs to take care of 2)"?

Comment: Oops. My bad. Should be 500 keys using 500 threads.

Comment: `how do I divide ...?` do you ask because of performance concerns?

Comment: Yes. I need maximum optimization, but I can't do it without knowing how to divide the work for specific threads like the examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you modify your basic kernel structure like this:

```
__global__ void UpdateKeys(Request* vector, int size, int seed, int qt_threads){
   curandState_t state;
   curand_init(seed, threadIdx.x, 0, &state);
   int id = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
   int gid = blockDim.x * gridDim.x;
   for(; id < size; id += gid){
       vector[id].key_ = (curand(&state) % 100) / 100;
   }
}
```

then it should be possible for any legal one dimensional block size (and number of one dimensional blocks) to process as many or as few inputs as you choose to provide via the `size` parameter. If you run more threads than keys, some threads will do nothing. If you run less threads than keys, some threads will process multiple keys.

Comment: It is a good solution, but you assume that I would use more than 1 grid, right? And, I think, it would lose me time.

Comment: @ÁlvaroEspíndola: Err, no.

Comment: No for the time losing or for the grid?

Comment: For the grid. You only need a single kernel launch

Comment: Yes, but I can't use grids as now because I plan using then foward for another thing.

Comment: At this point I have no idea what you are trying to ask and I doubt you do either. Your question contains a kernel, which I have proposed a *tiny* modification  to in order to do precisely  what you ahow in your question. Isn't that what you asked?

Comment: Your modification is indeed valid, I may have expressed my self wrong. The only thing that I can't use is Grids, because I will need them foward in the code. Besides that, your answer works.